# How to play sound using media volume instead of ring volume in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play a sound but my current code bases the volume off of the ringtone volume. How to I change this to media volume?

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer?
```

...

```
func playSound(name: String) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "mp3")!

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard let player = player else { return }

            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

...

```
playSound(name: "baby")
```

Answer (score 0):

Only set that before you put some url into the player.

```
 try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
```

Answer (score -1):

To play sound using media volume you should do like this:

```
func play(){

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Plop", ofType: "mp3")!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            bombSoundEffect = sound
            sound.play()
        } catch {
            // couldn't load file :(
        }
    }
```